# paypal subscription error when doing the purchase on live site, but works on sandbox. "Action could not be completed"

Tags: php, paypal

I have 2 purchase button for paypal.

1. Regular checkout (this works perfectly well in sandbox AND live site)
2. A recurring payment.

The recurring button works perfectly well in the sandbox. I can make the transaction, no problem. Everything is good.

If I switch over the live site, my #1 (regular checkout button still works with a real money exchange), but my recurring button doesn't.

It Does bring me to the paypal subscription payment page. I use a paypal account with real live credits in it (NOT the same account as the seller's account). And when I press login, I see:

> Sorry — your last action could not be completed
>
> If you were making a
> purchase or sending money, we recommend that you check both your
> PayPal account and your email for a transaction confirmation after 30
> minutes.
>
> If you came to this page from another website, please return to that
> site (don't use your browser's Back button) and restart your activity.
>
> If you came from PayPal's website, click the PayPal logo in the
> upper-left corner to return to our home page and restart your
> activity. You might have to log in again.

I tried the following:

1. Change browser, FF and Chrome
2. Clear all cache, cookies
3. I am not using frames as other people have suggested

Nothing works.

here is my code to submit to paypal, in case someone sees a mistake:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/webscr" id="myform" method="post">             
        
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">            
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="MY EMAIL HERE">            
        
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="MY NAME Subscription">            
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">            
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">              
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" id="currency" value="<?=$currency?>">            
<input type="hidden" name="a3" id="hiddentotal2" value="<?=$total2?>">            
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">            
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">            
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">            
        
<input type="hidden" name="custom" id="custompaypal" value="<?=$custom?>">            
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.mysite..../notify_paypal.php">            
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mysite..../myorders.php">            
<input class="submit-button2" type="submit" name="submit" value="PURCHASE SUB" />            
</form>
```

What could be causing this and how can I fix this.

Comment: seems to be a current problem with PayPal - not sure what the issue is: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Payments/Sorry-your-last-action-could-not-be-completed/m-p/1064025/thread-id/59727/highlight/false

Comment: @sol I can see other people having the issue, but do you think the issue is me as a "merchant" or me as a "client" when I do my test transaction ?